# Normal Push Notification Permissions after already having Silent Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that has already been receiving **silent** push notifications for some time now. I now have a requirement of adding normal push notifications that will show up in a user's notification center and as a banner.

Initially, all I was doing was registering for push notifications without requesting authorization (because silent notifications don't require authorization):

```
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

The issue now is that there's no prompt to grant or deny notification permissions when I do request authorization like so:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { granted, error in
    // Handle response
}
```

I would think that since I've never called `requestAuthorization` before, there would be a prompt. But it seems like since the device has registered for (silent) notifications in the past, there won't be any prompt.

Am I correct in this reasoning? And is my only option now to present my own modal and direct the user to enable notifications in Settings manually?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked this in my app and I've removed call to

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { granted, error in
    // Handle response
}
```

After this (on fresh install) and only registerForRemoteNotifications call, I got notification token, there was no prompt and notification message and badge can't be shown.

Then I restored requestAuthorization call, run app and prompt has shown up. So this would point that you're wrong and you must see prompt after first requestAuthorization call.

My guess is that you've already agreed on prompt sometime ago.
Check in phone Settings->"YourApp"->Notifications. 
If you have already agreed - there will be info there.

Try uninstalling the app and check again if prompt shows.

Comment: It’s helpful to know that I must have requested authorization at some point in the past (which I may have forgotten about - totally possible), but I still don’t get the prompt after uninstalling. I’ve read elsewhere that you need to keep the app deleted for 24 hours before the status gets reset, but that depends on the iOS version. It’s not very clear how Apple persists that information, I haven’t been able to find any definitive answer about that.